# I have successfully installed code runner extension in my VS Code. but play button is not showing only in my c extension files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have successfully installed code runner extension in my VS Code. It is showing and running in other  program files, but in my c extension file play button is not visible

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFSOL.png)

[image]

Comment: Inside VSCode, you could try the following `ctrl + shift + P` and look for restart server or restart the editor

Comment: I tried but it is not working

Comment: perhaps you could then try to uninstall VSCode completely from your system, then restart your machine and try downloading it again and install any extensions you may need for this to work. If this still does not work id try and see if I can get an earlier version since the latest one is not working for you. Hope this helps :)